# How to Merge Java scripts to change font size and font color By getting User Input

Tags: javascript

I have written separate Javascript to change font color and font size. How to merge it to make the change of both simultaneously to the same font.

```
`enter code here`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <form>
      <select onchange="ChangeFont (this);" size="1">
         <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
         <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
         <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
         <option value="0.75">0.75</option> 
         <option selected="1.0">1.0</option>
         <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
         <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
         <option value="1.75">1.75</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <span id="fontTest" style="font-size-adjust: 0.6">Change font-size-adjust</span>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeFont (selectTag) {            
            // Returns the index of the selected option
            var whichSelected = selectTag.selectedIndex;
            // Returns the selected options values
            var selectState = selectTag.options[whichSelected].text;
            var fontTest = document.getElementById ("fontTest");
            if ('fontSizeAdjust' in fontTest.style) {
                fontTest.style.fontSizeAdjust = selectState;
            } else {
                alert ("Your browser doesn't support this example!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Another one is font color change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   </form>
       <select name="color" type="text" onchange="changeBackground(this);" >
           <option value="select">Select</option>
           <option value="blue">Blue</option>
           <option value="green">Green</option>
           <option value="white">White</option>
           <option value="black">Black</option>
       </select>
       <span id="coltext">This text should have the same color as you put in the text box</span>
   </form>
   <script>
     function changeBackground(obj) {
       document.getElementById("coltext").style.color = obj.value;
     }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to merge these two Java scripts? Please help me.

Comment: Please provide expected behavior

Comment: two inputs get from users to change font and size, both have seperate IDs. so help me to make it single javascript function to do this.

Comment: Thanks Mukto Mona to align my code..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <form>
      <select onchange="ChangeBackgroundFont(this,'font');" size="1">
         <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
         <option value="0.25">0.25</option>
         <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
         <option value="0.75">0.75</option> 
         <option selected="1.0">1.0</option>
         <option value="1.25">1.25</option>
         <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
         <option value="1.75">1.75</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <select name="color" type="text" onchange="ChangeBackgroundFont(this,'background');" >
           <option value="select">Select</option>
           <option value="blue">Blue</option>
           <option value="green">Green</option>
           <option value="white">White</option>
           <option value="black">Black</option>
       </select>
      <span id="fontbackgroundTest" style="font-size-adjust: 0.6">Change font-size-adjust</span>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeBackgroundFont (selectTag,type) {      
          if(type=="font") {     
              // Returns the index of the selected option
              var whichSelected = selectTag.selectedIndex;
              // Returns the selected options values
              var selectState = selectTag.options[whichSelected].text;
              var fontTest = document.getElementById ("fontbackgroundTest");
              if ('fontSizeAdjust' in fontTest.style) {
                  fontTest.style.fontSizeAdjust = selectState;
              } else {
                  alert ("Your browser doesn't support this example!");
              }
            }else{
                document.getElementById("fontbackgroundTest").style.color = selectTag.value;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I did for you enjoy ):

Comment: Wow..Its Great Jayram Prajapati. Thank you so much. Keep in touch..:)